# Почему для проекта в Intellij Idea нельзя открыть вкладку Сhanges?

Tags: intellij-idea

Почему для проекта в *Intellij Idea* нельзя открыть вкладку *Сhanges*? У проекта со сходной структурой эта вкладка видна, а у данного проекта - нет. Проект загружен из *SVN*. Какие могут быть причины?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашла решение. После включения интеграции контроля версий:

**VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration**

вкладка *Ghanges* появилась.